# Angular 8 - How to pass additional values through interceptor

Tags: node.js, angular

I am new to angular. I am using interceptor to pass JWT Token into node server. Whenever i call any of httpClient functions, the interceptor triggers as expected and i am able to get my JWT token in my node. Now i want to pass an object (args) to my node server. But i couldn't. Can anyone please help me.
Here is my code..

```
#Home Component

   var args = {
      uid: "12345",
    };

    this.api.myFunc(args).subscribe((result) => {
      // doSomething
      }


#API Service

myFunc(args) {  
    return this.httpClient
      .get("myFunc/", args)
      .pipe(
        map((data) => {
          return data;
        }),
        retry(1),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }


#Interceptor Code

intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (this.strHttp) {      
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${this.auth.getToken()}`,          
        },
      });
    }

    return next.handle(request);
  }
```

Comment: do you want args to be added in headers or modify request body data ?

Comment: There has been en open issue in the Angular repo for this since 2017 - but - I think this might actually picked up. You can still add arbitrary data through headers etc of course.

Comment: I want args to be added into the header

Comment: Then your rags need to be stringified. What's the issue?

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Error on Angular or you can't get args on your NodeJs server. Can you show some code of your NodeJs server

Comment: The problem is, dont know how to add additional parameter into the header,. I am having more than 25 httpCLient function which are called from different components. So far, without adding interceptor concept all my http functions works fine. Most of my http functions need input arguments. So i have pass these arguments. Here is my server code...Sorry...Not able to add the Server code here...

Comment: A line next to Authorization like Data: {uid:12345} (In interceptor Code) will solve the problem.. But to pass these values from different components is the task. I tried by passing these arguments through a service from the components but before the service updates the value the interceptor executed. So the http functions are called without arguments, which gives me error... Anyone please help.. Thanks in advance..